# A property set as private or without private keyword. What is the difference?

Tags: c#, properties

I am setting the property of a class like that

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

But i can also set the property like that

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

I want to know the difference between these? and what scope they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case `public string Name { get; private set; }`
Using private set means that the property is `ReadOnly` from the outside. Its useful when  you have a read only property and don't want to explicitly declare the backing variable.

`public string Name { get; private set; }` it  is same as :

```
private string _Name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    private set { _Name = value; }
}
```

Comment: The latter two things are not actually the same.  From within the class, `this.Name = "bill"` is valid with the first implementation, but *not* the second.

Answer (score 5):

It means you cannot set this property from class instance. Only member of same class can set it. Hence for outsiders this property becomes `read-only` property.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }

    public string Name2 { get; private set; }

    public string Name3 { get { return Name2; } set { Name2 = value; }
}
```

Then

```
Foo f = new Foo();

f.Name1 = ""; // No Error

f.Name2 = ""; // Error.

f.Name3 = ""; // No Error
```

`Name3` will set value in `Name2` but setting value in `Name2` directly is not possible.

> and what scope they have?

Since `Name1` and `Name3` property are public so they and their get and set methods are available everywhere.

`Name3` is also public but its set is private so property and get method will be available everywhere. Set method scope is limited to class only (`private` access modifier has scope inside entity where it is defined).

Answer (score 3):

The first one will have `Set` and `Get` methods available out of your class. The second one will have a `Get` method available out of your class but the `Set` method will only be available within your class. This usually denotes read only behaviour.